# How often does grok_exporter publish processed metrics?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

How often data is published by `grok_exporter` compared to how data is scraped by Prometheus?

For instance, if grok_eporter processes 100 lines by is 1 second, and Prometheus calls the grok_exporter metrics api to scrape data, the guage published seem to always be the final guage that was last processed by grok exporter within the second

The example below further illustrates my point:

Let's say the log file being processed. by `grok_exporter` is this, with each line representing a guage value

**1 second**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**Prometheus then calls the metrics api published by grok_exporter. after 1 second**

Prometheus get **5** as the guage value, How do I make prometheus scrape each and every guage(line) processed by *grok_exporter*?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with [`grok_exporter`](https://github.com/fstab/grok_exporter)

Generally with logs to metrics solutions, the metrics are calculated by the number of logs that match a pattern e.g. counting `response_code=500` **not** using values (`500`) contained in logs as metrics.

If `grok_exporter` works like this, that may be your issue and, what you want to do, is not possible.

If the log line itself contains a metric value, pursuing my example a log contains `total_count_http_server_errors=800`, you may (!) need a different solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering, However `grok_exporter` uses regex to publish values from each line using a defined pattern. So If I define a guage regex `number_successful`, `grok_exporter` publishes get a `number_successful=${regexMatchHere}` for each line. 

My question now is, how to make sure no values are skipped cos `grok_exporter` publishes last process line at any moment

If `prometheus` scraps less frequently more than `grok_exporter` puublishes, some data become lost

Comment: Yes, I think you're example demonstrates my point. "for each line" means the value is your metric value. What I think you want the log lines to represent is a value per log line that can be summed or counted by Prometheus when it scrapes the exporter in order to calculate the metric value.